# How do I use a replace method to remove or replace commas in this scala template

Tags: javascript, java, html, scala, jsp

I'm new to Scala templates and the Play framework. In this Scala html fragment how can I use a replace method similar to Javascript to replace  commas to other character(s) when the options html data-type attribute  values output?

```
<select class="chosen-filter reporting-filter columnSelect">
    <option value="-1"></option>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) { %>
    <option value="<%= columns[i].id %>" data-type="<%=columns[i].type %>" <%if(columns[i].type == 'picklist') { %> data-list="<%= columns[i].options %>"<% } %>>
    <%= columns[i].displayName %>
    </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
```

So instead of the values looking like

```
<option data-type="example" data-list="Yes,No">example 1</option>
<option data-type="example" data-list="Yes,No">example 2</option>
```

It would be

```
<option data-type="example" data-list="Yes&#44;No">example 1</option>
<option data-type="example" data-list="Yes&#44;No">example 2</option>
```

Comment: Can't you do `data-list="<%= columns[i].options.replace(",", "&#44;") %>"`?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add the toString() method in order to use the replace() method.

```
<%if(columns[i].type == 'picklist') { %> data-list="<%= columns[i].options.toString().replace(',','&#44;') %>"<% } %>>
```